# How to open and modify an RTF file using .replace and regex and then write line by line with Nodejs and remove "stubborn" double \\?

Tags: node.js, regex, asynchronous, replace

I am working with node.js and I am processing some RTF files (that started as PDFs). The specific problem I have concerns opening the RTF files, removing some "unwanted" parts and then writing to a few file.

I am trying to remove extraneous markup such as |-- and other characters that were used to format the document. I would like text (which happens to be in Japanese), nothing else.

Here's the problem I have encountered. In the original file, the RTF looks like this (just a sample):

```
\f2\fs24 \
\pard\pardeftab720\sl235\slmult1\partightenfactor0

\f0\fs20 \cf0 \'a1\'a1
\f2\fs24 \
\pard\pardeftab720\sl-2\partightenfactor0

\f1 \cf0 \
\pard\pardeftab720\ri5880\sl253\slmult1\partightenfactor0
```

I am able to remove the undesired characters as of right now. However, when writing to the new file, I get this one very specific problem:

```
\f2\fs24 
\\pard\pardeftab720\sl235\slmult1\partightenfactor0\f0\fs20 
\cf0 \'a1\'a1\f2\fs24 \\pard\pardeftab720\sl-2\partightenfactor0\f1 
\cf0 
\\pard\pardeftab720\ri5880\sl253\slmult1\partightenfactor0\f0\fs19 
\cf0
```

The problem is with the

```
\\pard
```

parts. The double '\\' means that the word 'pard' shows up in the RTF file as output. I've tried used .replace with regex, but the problem seems to be with the actual writing. No matter what I do, when it writes to the file I end up with the '\\pard' instead of '\pard'.

Here is the code I have as of right now:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
let rtf = './sample.rtf';


let regex = /\?\\\'a3\\\'ad|\\\'a3\\\'ad|\?\\\'a9\\\'d3|\\\'a9\\\'d3|\?\\u9487|\\u9487|\\uc0\\u9491|\?\?\\u9475|\?\\u9473|\\u9473|\?\\u9474|\\u9474|\?\\u9475|\\u9475|\?\\u9472|\\u9472|\\\'a9\\\'cc|\\\'a9\\\'d0|\\\'a9\\\'cf|\\\'a9\\\'e3|\\\'a9\\'c7|\\'a9\\\'c4|\?\\u9473|\\u9473|\?\\u9487|\\u9487|\\\'a9\\\'c4\\\'a9\\\'e0|\\uc0\\u9491|\\\'a9\\\'e0|\\\'a9\\\'c0/gi;



let readStream = fs.createReadStream('sample.rtf');
let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(`${rtf}-clean.rtf`);

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: readStream,
  output: writeStream,
  crlfDelay: Infinity
});

rl.on("line", ((line) => {
  line = line.replace(regex, "");
  writeStream.write(line);
}));

rl.on("close", (() => {
  console.log('done');
}))
```

If anyone has any suggestions or insight, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is short, you should not double escape, when you create a `literal` regex (a regex pattern that starts and ends with a slash `'/'`).

**So remove all those double escapes.**

Comment: Thanks. That didn't appear to be the problem. I ran it again, this time without any .replace. It appears that even just opening the file and writing to the file makes this problem appear. A line such as ```\f2\fs24 \
\pard\pardeftab720\sl235\slmult1\partightenfactor0``` will get written as ```\\pard```.